# Shortcuts to files lead nowhere

Tags: windows-vista

I was adding some files to Dropbox and accidently added some I didn't want to.  I thought I removed them and put them into a new file back in My Documents, but when I looked, they weren't there.

I searched and brought up the file shortcuts in Recent Items. When I click on them... nothing. It tells me they were "moved or changed."

When I click on their properties and try to click anything there, it tells me the name is not valid and that I should be sure the path and file name are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hive you performed a file search for the missing files? Checked your Recycle Bin?

It sounds very much like you've deleted the wrong ones (ie the originals, not the shortcuts).

If you cannot find them you need to run some kind of data recovery tool.